# What does printf return c but getting an error

Tags: c, printf

```
int a = 0;
#pragma omp parallel private(a)
{
 a++;
 printf ("%d", a);
}
```

I got an exercise where I have to say what the output of printf is but it shows " 
main.c:13:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token "
and I do not know what to do :( sorry I am a noob to c

Comment: What compiler and platform are you using

Comment: There aren't 13 lines here, so you didn't show the full code. Is this inside a function?

Comment: This is not actually inside a function it was simply that code part given. I used the online c compiler at https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler to just quick run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your instructions in a function, in this case `main` (which is the function which will be run first in your program):

```
int a = 0;
#pragma omp parallel private(a)

int main()
{
    a++;
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I totally forgot about that was wondering how to make it work since it was actually a given code so I didn't think they could have forgotten something.